# How to set Server Sent Event to EventStream in browser Not Document in Golang

Tags: go, http, server-sent-events, go-gin

I would like to implement Server Sent Event (SSE) with golang, This is the code that I have tried: https://github.com/gin-gonic/examples/blob/master/server-sent-event/main.go

but when I test this SSE API in browser I got the response is Document not EventStream:
[image]

and I cant Fetch Data for each stream:
[image]

Is there anyone who can help me, please?